# CSS/JavaScript manager for django

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

Is there a CSS and/or JavaScript manager module for django?

What I am looking for in functionality:

- I would like to be able to define which stylesheets and javascript files to load, on a per view basis (this by itself is easy to do in bare django, but bear with me...)
- I would like the plugin to automatically combine/optimize the "source" CSS/JS and insert the output into the appropriate view.

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [django-mediagenerator](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-mediagenerator).